# Reading file char by char in C++

Tags: c++

I have this txt file

```js
ENG222;COMPUTER PROGRAMMING II;2;6;C;D;DR. JIM
ENG111;COMPUTER PROGRAMMING I;1;4;C;D;DR. JOHNSON
ENG313;MATH I;3;3;E;D;DR. ALISSON
ENG104;CHEM;1;5;C;D;DR. SAM
```

how can i read and write this file to ArrayList from ';' to ';' in C++

Comment: Why would you read it character by character? Don't you want to read a line and split it at `;` characters?

Comment: Hi, Would you mind adding more details to the question. Do you want all items to be stored as individual elements in the arraylist. Did you tried writing a program and encountered specific errors. Do you mind sharing that, if you have one ? Thanks and Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that you mean java's `ArrayList` which has an equivalence in C++ of `std::vector`. Also I assume that you want to store each string between the semicolons inside the `ArrayList`. I also assume that the file is called `input.txt`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings;

    std::ifstream input("input.txt");

    std::string tempString;
    while (std::getline(input, tempString, ';'))            
        strings.push_back(tempString);

    for (auto& str : strings)
        std::cout << str << '\n';

}
```

Output:

```
ENG222
COMPUTER PROGRAMMING II
2
6
C
D
DR. JIM
ENG111
COMPUTER PROGRAMMING I
1
4
C
D
DR. JOHNSON
ENG313
MATH I
3
3
E
D
DR. ALISSON
ENG104
CHEM
1
5
C
D
DR. SAM
```

---

**Edit:**

I've understood from the comments that you want to add each column to an `ArrayList`. I'll assume that the number of columns is just `7`. If you want the number of columns to vary, you can input the value somehow. maybe by reading the value from the file (`input >> columns`) or by reading it from the standard input (`std::cin >> columns`). In this code, if some row contains only 4 values for example, I consider the rest of the 3 values to be empty.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");

    int columns = 7;

    /*

    // in case the columns count is not constant.

    // to read from the file. in this case, the number should be at the begining of the file.
    input >> columns;

    // to read from the standard input (from the terminal).
    std::cin >> columns;

    // to white spaces.
    input.ignore();

    */

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> values(columns);


    std::string tempLineString;
    std::string tempWordString;

    while (!input.eof())
    {
        std::getline(input, tempLineString);
        std::istringstream iss(tempLineString);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < columns && std::getline(iss, tempWordString, ';'))
        {
            values[i].push_back(tempWordString);
            i++;
        }

        while (i < columns)
            values[i++].push_back("");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Column " << i + 1 << " values: \n";
        for (auto& str : values[i])
            std::cout << str << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Column 1 values:
ENG222
ENG111
ENG313
ENG104

Column 2 values:
COMPUTER PROGRAMMING II
COMPUTER PROGRAMMING I
MATH I
CHEM

Column 3 values:
2
1
3
1

Column 4 values:
6
4
3
5

Column 5 values:
C
C
E
C

Column 6 values:
D
D
D
D

Column 7 values:
DR. JIM
DR. JOHNSON
DR. ALISSON
DR. SAM
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but i actually want to do separate these values type by type in array.

Comment: @SalazarCidas What do you mean by "separate these values type by type in array"?

Comment: for example string[] [firstcolmn] = ENG222, ENG111, ENG313

Comment: string[] [secndcolmn] = COMPUTER PROGRAMMING II, COMPUTER PROGRAMMING I,

Comment: @SalazarCidas Sure, But That will assume that there are only 6 columns. Is that okay?

Comment: so i have an another question if i dont know how many rows and cols how can i do?

Comment: @SalazarCidas You're welcome! I'm preparing an example now. In case the size is not a constant, you'd require the data to be inputed somehow. In the example I'm preparing, the number of columns will be at the begining of the file.